# I'm writing a backend for a website using flask, but for some reason the session is lost?

Tags: python, flask

There is some code in which I log in a user and add him to the session:

```py
session['username'] = user[1]
```

but for some reason later, when I check what information is saved in the session

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    response_object = {'status': 'success'}
    response_object['message'] = session.get('username')

    return jsonify(response_object)
```

but the flask page displays **{"message":null,"status":"success"}** Help, what is the error?

I try this string:

```py
session.modified = true
```

Comment: did you check `user[1]` value?

Comment: @atif_sreezon ues I chech it by print(session['username']) in function with `session['username'] = user[1]`, but when I try to check it in / page (`session['username'] = user[1]` - in page /login) I have? what you can see